# Strange SSL certificate and https website

Tags: ssl-certificate, https

Checking this https://racq.travelinsurancepartners.com.au/, you will find the browser is displaying things OK.

However, browsing https://www.travelinsurancepartners.com.au/, you will see the browser reports the SSL certificate is for covermore.com, and warn about security problem.

Yes, the certificate is for covermore.com, however, how come IE, Firefox and Chrome all do not report problem when accessing https://racq.travelinsurancepartners.com.au  ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I look at this SSL certificate :

- the *Object* is "covermore.com", which "identifies the entity associated with the public key stored in the subject public key field" (see [RFC 5280, section 4.1.2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6)) ;
- the *Subject Alternative Name* has a list of valid domain names (see [RFC 5280, section 4.2.1.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6)) which contains **racq.travelinsurancepartners.com.au**

However, **[www.travelinsurancepartners.com.au](http://www.travelinsurancepartners.com.au)** is not part of the valid domains list, so that your browser warms you.

One SSL certificate can handle multiple domains or subdomains.

Comment: I had purchased a few SSL certificates. Basically mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. Certificates  with a few sub domains are more expensive. so, is it legitimate to have ssl for subdomain.mydomain.com, but not www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com?

Comment: You should use a SSL certificate when communications need to be encrypted. For example, a login page. The trend is to encrypt anything and so have SSL for all your pages.You may have one or more certificates. However, you should verify that you can install multiple certificates. As StartSSL offer free SSL certificates for one domain, I use a different certificate for all my domains and subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) where you will see: m.racq.travelinsurancepartners.com.au as one of the many alternative names.

Check out the CA Browser forum website http://cabforum.org for more info.